# Best practices to use Magento rest & soap web API together for android

Tags: android, rest, magento, soap, asp.net-web-api

I am working on Magento based m-commerce android app. In which I have to use both REST & SOAP web api. Because REST api didn't provide all functionality as SOAP. And to use only SOAP api for whole app will reduce app performance and also UX due to overheads and xml.

What is the best practices for doing this thing? Is there any simple option available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience Magento SOAP API is too slow, So you can select REST and try to add extra features to Magento REST API by rewriting the modules. Here is a sample tutorial for do
[Extending the Magento REST API](http://web.archive.org/web/20130512072025/http://magepim.com/news/Extending-the-Magento-REST-API-part-1_13)

In this way you can achieve all the functionality in REST API as same as SOAP API.

Comment: Thanks Remees instant for reply. Can you tell me how much will it cost to extend the Magento REST API in terms of time and effort?

Comment: Its purely based on the needs, if there is magento developers it will be easy. They can develop it in ease . The problem is understanding the magento and link it with app, once you done this the datas may change but the process for all the function are same.

Comment: Thanks Remees ,I got the idea.